# How to link framework only under Debug configuration?

Tags: xcode

I have a framework which I only want to link under Debug configuration, i.e., I have to make sure it is not linked under Release configuration. How can I do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

no need for to targets or any ifdef stuff.

1. dont add it to any target
2. and then add to the `linker flags` for the config only

[image]

works for static libs and dylibs and also frameworks

Comment: The question was about a system framework. A private one. Yeah